# Pivot table report filters: can I force a value not found in the source data? Or filter on "not blank"?

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

- My data has a *CCA?* column containing either "CCA" or a blank value.
- My pivot table uses a report filter on the *CCA?* field.
- I only want the pivot table to show rows where *CCA?* equals "CCA".
- Because this is a report filter, I can select "CCA" from the dropdown. (screenshot 1)

Here's my problem:

- If no row has *CCA?* equals "CCA", "CCA"is lo longer available as a report filter value; the report filter reverts to "(All)"; and all rows are used in the table. I want no rows to be used.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to force the filter value to "CCA" if no rows contain that value?

There is another method through which I can filter the data: I can swap the report filter for a standard field added to the top of the *Rows* area, then add a Value Filter to the *Row Labels* column (Screenshot 2), but it creates a cosmetic issue: the *CCA?* field appears in the pivot table. (Screenshot 3)

**Question 2:** Is there a way to hide that field from the table?

Screenshot 1:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Screenshot 3:

[image: Screenshot 3]